# What is the relation between mathematical approximation of Big O notation and pratical one in programming

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I have a question about asymptotic complexity, specifically Big O notation.

Mathematically speaking: we have a function T(n) it's output :  the amount of time taken by our algorithm.

for example T(n) = 1000 + 10n .
We choose a simple function F(n) = n , and for some large natural number N and constant C , T(n) <= C.F(n) which is equivalent to that T(n) belonging O(f(n)) ( sets of functions which T one of them dominated by C.F(n) ).

My specific question: I didn't get the point of upper bounds , where from a specific input N , all T(n) points are upper bounded by F(n) points .

What's the relation between that mathematical approximation and worst-best case complexity in computer science and Big O notation

[image: Simple graph of two functions]

Comment: even if it was 1000n a n² will always be worse (even on smaller'sh input sizes). that kind of fine graining is only worth on really big input sizes and only after every other optimization was done.

Comment: 1000n bellong to O(n) by the way, you need to precise , but yes , we're talking for a large input size , for example two sorting algorithms , represented with the felllowing fonctions : u = n.log2(n) & v = 10.n , u  algorithms start giving optimal values for n >= 10^50

Comment: @wassdz31 binary search is O(log(n)). Sorting a list is usually O(n·log(n))

Comment: Thanks @Ripi2 , it was a writing fault

Comment: Draw a `straight`, and a `log(n)` and a `n·long(n)` and `n^2` too. For some "n" each function is bigger than the previous. For small "n" it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Practically, anything that grows faster than n log n needs thought, because your own testing is probably on small examples, but real life use might have much larger inputs, especially if part of the problem is a database that accumulates information over time. Anything growing faster than n log n might mean that even though your tests run perfectly well the system is unusably slow in real life.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about the topic.
This mathematical proof is just an approximation to explain that our function T(n) [ which it's output number of instructions or steps our algorithm spend to do some specific job ] is upper bounded by the equivalent function C.F(n) where C is some specific big constant > 0 . so our upper bound refers to the worst-case complexity , that our algorithm can reach ( and can reach because mathematically T(n) and F(n) intersect in some specific big N > 0 which become a supremum ( upper bound bellong to our function) ) .
so in resume , it's an approximation to prove that the worst case complexity is an upper bound ( or supremum ) that our algorithm can reach .